# Looking for a Delphi library/component to read .Net app.config files

Tags: delphi, app-config

Subject line says it all really.

Some Googling has revealed a puzzling lack of relevant information. Some pointers to an existing implement would be great!

Raymond.

Answer (score 5):

Those are strictly simple XML files - you can even get a [XML schema file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1fk1t1t0.aspx) describing their exact structure.

Shouldn't be too hard to parse that in Delphi and present it in whatever way you see fit. You don't need any specific library or component - just XML parsing and a bit of patience :-)

Comment: A schema tells you the structure of the XML, but tells you nothing about how to interpret/work with that structure.  An API/library encapsulation will often contain knowledge about the content that is not immediately apparent from a bare-bones structural description.  e.g. Would a document describing the MS Access database file format help you get data into/out of the file correctly?  The need for that "bit of patience" you referred to would be eliminated, or greatly reduced, by an encapsulation.  XML really isn't the Golden Path to clarity and access that some people seem to think.  imho.

Comment: I know it isn't hard :-), I just didn't feel like reinventing the wheel!

Comment: @Deltics: writing a correct MS Access file if I have a correct and complete documentation - why shouldn't this work? If a format specification is machine-readable like WSDL and WADL, and even can be used as input for code generators, developers can go home after lunch while others try to invent their own file format description language :)

Comment: @mjustin: The file format description tells you where you need to put the data, but doesn't help you get the data in the right place.  You then have to translate the knowledge contained in the file format specification into executable code that puts the right data in the right places.  Having an XSD does not give you executable code, it just gives you a convenient way to check that the executable code you write is actually correct.  But you still have to write the code.  The question - as I read it - is asking if anyone has already done the "writing executable code" part.

Comment: Yes - I'm after an existing piece of Delphi code that reads the app.config files and provides access to their contents :-)